# Neural nets (or similar) for regression problems

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, linear-regression, feature-extraction

The motivating idea behind neural nets seems to be that they learn the "right" features to apply logistic regression to. Is there a similar approach for linear regression? (or just regression problems in general?)

Would doing the obvious thing of removing the application of a sigmoid function for all neurons (ie, including the hidden layers) make sense/work? (ie, each neuron is performing linear regression instead of logistic regression).

Alternatively, would doing the (maybe even more obvious) thing of just scaling output values to [0,1] work? (intuitively I would think not, as the sigmoid function seems like it would cause the net to arbitrarily favor extreme values) (edit: though I was just searching around some more, and saw that one technique is to scale based on mean and variance, which seems like it might deal with this issue -- so maybe this is more viable than I thought).

Or is there some other technique for doing "feature learning" for regression problems?

Comment: Deep Learning can help you do feature learning. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [applet](http://neuron.eng.wayne.edu/bpFunctionApprox/bpFunctionApprox.html). Try to learn different functions. When you dictate linear activation functions at both hidden and output layers, it even fails to learn the quadratic function. At least one layer needs to be set to sigmoid function, see figures below.

[image][image]

There are different kinds of scaling. Standard scaling, as you mentioned, eliminates the impact of mean and standard deviation of the training sample, is most often used in machine learning. Just make sure you are using the same mean and std value from training sample in the test sample.

The reason why scaling is required is because the output of sigmoid function ranges at (0,1). I didn't try, but I think it is better to scale the output even if you select linear function at output layer. Otherwise large input at hidden layer (with sigmoid) won't lead to drastic output (the sigmoid function is approximately linear when the input is at a small range, out of such range will make the output changes much slowly). You can try this by yourself in your own data.

Besides, if you have various features, the feature normalization that makes different features in the same scale is also recommended. The scaling speeds up gradient descent by avoiding many extra iterations that are required when one or more features take on much larger values than the rest.

As @Ray mentioned, [deep learning](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/ki2012_schulz_deeplearning.pdf) that many levels of features are involved can help you with the feature learning, it's not all linear combinations though.